# Issue when adding a new column in WooCommerce admin order list displaying product names

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I am trying to display a column on the Orders page (admin). In that column, show each product in the order.

The idea is to be able to quickly see the products that have been ordered.

Adding the column works fine, but getting the products is not working. All I get is `Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError`

**Here's is the code:**

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'products_column_create_products', 20 );
function products_column_create_products( $columns ) {

    $reordered_columns = array();

        foreach( $columns as $key => $column ) {

            $reordered_columns[$key] = $column;

            if ( $key == 'order_number' ) {

                $reordered_columns['products'] = __( 'Products','woocommerce' );

            }
        }

    return $reordered_columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'products_column_show_products', 20, 3 );
function products_column_show_products($column, $post_id, $order){

    if ('products' != $column) return;

    global $order;

        $details = array();

            foreach($order->get_items() as $item)

            $details[] = '<a href="' . $item->get_product()->get_permalink() . '">' . $item->get_name() . '</a>  × ' . $item->get_quantity() .'<br>';

        echo count($details) > 0 ? implode('<br>', $details) : '–';
}
```

---

I don't know how to fix it, so if anyone can give advice please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some minor bugs, for example:

- You indicate that the `products_column_show_products()` callback function expects 3 arguments, while the `manage_{$post->post_type}_posts_custom_column` WordPress hook contains 2 parameters. The `$column_name` and the `$post_id`
- There is no need to use `global $order;`, via the `$post_id`,
  you can access the order with `wc_get_order( $post_id );`

So this should suffice:

```php
// Add a Header
function filter_manage_edit_shop_order_columns( $columns ) {
    // Loop trough existing columns
    foreach ( $columns as $key => $name ) {

        $new_columns[ $key ] = $name;

        // Add after order status column
        if ( $key === 'order_number' ) {
            $new_columns['order_products'] = __( 'Products', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }

    return $new_columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'filter_manage_edit_shop_order_columns', 10, 1 );

// Populate the Column
function action_manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    // Compare
    if ( $column == 'order_products' ) {
        // Get order
        $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );
        
        echo '<ul>';
    
        // Going through order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            // Get product object
            $product = $item->get_product();
            
            echo '<li><a href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $item->get_name() . '</a> &times; ' . $item->get_quantity() . '</li>';
        }
        
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'action_manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 10, 2 );
```