# Add a product filter dropdown on WooCommerce admin orders list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, backend, product, orders

I'm trying to add a product filter dropdown on WooCommerce admin orders list.

[image]

Based on [How to create a filter dropdown on WooCommerce admin orders list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62452517/11987538) answer code, this is my attempt:

```php
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'add_shop_order_filter_by_state');
function add_shop_order_filter_by_state(){
    global $pagenow, $typenow;
    $filter_id   = 'product_name';
    $current     = isset($_GET[$filter_id])? $_GET[$filter_id] : '';
    if( 'shop_order' === $typenow && 'edit.php' === $pagenow ) {
        echo '<select name="'.$filter_id.'">
            <option value="">'.__( 'Filter by product', 'socap' )."</option>";
            $args = array(
              'post_type'   => array( 'product' ),
              'orderby'     => 'date',
              'order'       => 'desc',
              'posts_per_page'      => -1
            );
            $popular_products = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $popular_products->have_posts() ) :
              while ( $popular_products->have_posts() ) : $popular_products->the_post();
                $nvselected = "";
                if($current == get_the_ID())
                {
                    $nvselected = 'selected="selected"';
                }
                echo '<option value="'.get_the_ID().'" '.$nvselected.'>'.get_the_title().'</option>';
              endwhile;
            endif;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        echo '</select>';
    }
}

// Process the filter dropdown for orders by shipping state
add_filter( 'request', 'process_admin_shop_order_filtering_by_state', 99 );
function process_admin_shop_order_filtering_by_state( $vars ) {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    $filter_id = 'product_name';

    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && 'shop_order' === $typenow 
    && isset( $_GET[$filter_id] ) && ! empty($_GET[$filter_id]) ) {
        //What i need to pass here ?
    }
    return $vars;
}
```

However this does not have the desired result, any advice?

Comment: @7uc1f3r I have same question and I want without custom column and order sorting based on product filter. Is it possible ?

Comment: @NikunjKathrotiya If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. However, it might be interesting if you wait for the answer to this question first.

Comment: @NikunjKathrotiya & Viral some feedback on my answer is always appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To add a product filter dropdown on WooCommerce admin orders list, you can use a custom SQL query to get all orderIDs in which the product name occurs. This via [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/).

- Instead of displaying all possible product names, I have limited these to product names that only appear in the existing orders. This to limit the drop-down list a bit.
- Explanation via comment tags added to my answer.

So you get:

```php
// Custom function to get the product names, that appear in the existing orders
function get_product_names() {
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_col("
        SELECT DISTINCT order_item_name 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items
        WHERE order_item_type = 'line_item'
    ");
} 

function action_restrict_manage_posts( $post_type, $which ) {   
    global $pagenow;

    // Compare
    if ( $post_type === 'shop_order' && $pagenow === 'edit.php' ) {
        $filter_id  = 'filter_product';
        $current    = isset( $_GET[$filter_id] ) ? $_GET[$filter_id] : '';

        // Create a drop-down list 
        echo '<select name="' . $filter_id . '">
        <option value="">' . __( 'Filter by product', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>';

        foreach ( get_product_names() as $product_name ) {          
            printf( '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $product_name, $product_name === $current ? '" selected="selected"' : '', ucfirst( $product_name ) );
        }
        
        echo '</select>';
    }
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'action_restrict_manage_posts', 10, 2 );

function action_pre_get_posts( $query ) {   
    global $pagenow, $post_type, $wpdb;

    $filter_id = 'filter_product';

    // Compare
    if ( $query->is_admin && $pagenow === 'edit.php' && $post_type === 'shop_order' && isset( $_GET[$filter_id] ) && $_GET[$filter_id] != '' ) {

        // Get all orderIDs in which the product name occurs
        $order_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
            SELECT DISTINCT order_id
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items
            WHERE order_item_type = 'line_item'
            AND order_item_name = '%s'
            ",  esc_attr( $_GET[$filter_id] ) 
        ) );

        // Set the new "meta query"
        $query->set( 'post__in', $order_ids );

        // Set "posts per page"
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 20 );

        // Set "paged"
        $query->set( 'paged', ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'action_pre_get_posts', 10, 1 );
```

---

**Note:** To display the product names, that an order contains in a custom column on WooCommerce admin orders list, you can use [Issue when adding a new column in WooCommerce admin order list displaying product names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66089192/11987538) answer code.

However, that code is not necessary for the above answer to work